# How to trigger checkbox onChange event through function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How to trigger checkbox onChange event through JavaScript function in React?

Introduction: I have group of checkboxes connected with global store in redux, they are categories pulled from API request. Default "search everywhere" checkbox is checked, if you check anything else "search everywhere" will be unchecked (by handleCheck function) and you can check as many categories as you want, until you check "search everywhere" again.

**gif how it works**

[image: gif how it works]

The problem: onChange event doesn't work when checkboxes are unchecked when you trigger handleCheck function. So as you can see, when you will check other categories, "search everywhere" doesn't remove from global store, and when you will chose "search everywhere" again, categories from strore don't deasapear as well.

```
const CategoriesView = () => {
  const [checkedIds, setCheckedIds] = useState(new Set(["everywhere"]));
  const categories = Array.from(useSelector((state) => state.categoriesStore.categories))
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const handleCheck = ({ id, checked }) => {
      if (checked) {
        if (id === "everywhere") {
              checkedIds.clear()
        } else {
              checkedIds.delete("everywhere")
        }
          checkedIds.add(id)
      } else {
          checkedIds.delete(id)
      }
      setCheckedIds(new Set(checkedIds))
    }

    const initial = {
        id: 'everywhere',
        name: 'Search everywhere'
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(allActions.addCategory(initial))
    }, [])

return (
      <>
          <Container>
              <Row>
                  <div className="container2 pl-5" >
                          <UlCategories>
                              <LiCategories key="everywhere">
                                      <CategoryLabel className="categories-container" htmlFor="everywhere">
                                          <input
                                          type="checkbox"
                                          id="everywhere"
                                          name="Search everywhere"
                                          data-special={true}
                                          checked={checkedIds.has("everywhere")}
                                          onChange={e => {
                                              handleCheck(e.target);
                                              if (e.target.checked) {
                                                  dispatch(allActions.addCategory(e.target))
                                              } else {
                                                  dispatch(allActions.removeCategory(e.target))
                                              }
                                              }
                                          }
                                          />
                                          <DivTitle>Search everywhere</DivTitle>
                                          <span className="categories-checkmark"/>
                                      </CategoryLabel>
                              </LiCategories>
                              {categories.splice(0, 19).map(category =>
                                  <LiCategories key={category.id}>
                                      <CategoryLabel className="categories-container" htmlFor={category.id}>
                                          <input
                                          type="checkbox"
                                          id={category.id}
                                          name={category.name}
                                          data-products={category.products}
                                          data-special={false}
                                          checked={checkedIds.has(category.id)}
                                          onChange={(e: any) => {
                                              handleCheck(e.target);
                                              if (e.target.checked) {
                                                  dispatch(allActions.addCategory(e.target))
                                              } else {
                                                  dispatch(allActions.removeCategory(e.target))
                                              }
                                              }
                                          }
                                          />
                                          <DivTitle>{category.name} {`(${category.products})`}</DivTitle>
                                          <span className="categories-checkmark"/>
                                      </CategoryLabel>
                                  </LiCategories>)
                              }
                          </UlCategories>
                  </div>

              </Row>
          </Container>
      </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Instead of merely dispatching the add/remove actions, you need to either create actions that will change the store like you actually want, or use the correct state you have in your `handleCheck` and dispatch that as state update. I'm sorry if this isn't very helpful but the problem is very obvious: the actions you dispatch simply do not fully reflect the state changes. All you need to do is fix that. You already know how to do this because you're doing it for the state. (Also, this is not about triggering an onChange event at all, even if that were a suitable solution, which it isn't)

Comment: Of course, you are right it's obvious. I focused so hard on a one solution, that I didn't see the big picture. Thank you for your wise advice @ChrisG

Comment: @ChrisG Maybe add as an answer?

Comment: @JoelPeltonen I don't see the point; even if somebody had the exact same problem in the future, how are they supposed to find this question? SO is about building a massive FAQ, not about getting rep.

Comment: @ChrisG I agree the nature of SO, but I, and I assume others, occasionally browse tags and open a bunch of unanswered questions to see if we can help (or close). Even super old ones. If this has an accepted answer, it won't be looked at in such a process.

Comment: Alternatively we could just vote to close/remove XY problems such as this and similars.